# WPF NotifyIcon ContextMenu with hardcode taskbar

Tags: c#, wpf, notifications, contextmenu

I try to implement [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36468/WPF-NotifyIcon-2) solution for my NotifyIcon. I did it by this way.

```
    private void InitNotifyIcon()
    {
        tbi = new TaskbarIcon();
        tbi.Icon = Properties.Resource.favIcon;
        tbi.DoubleClickCommand = new NotifyIconCommand(this);
        tbi.ToolTipText = "Double click - open window";
        this.WindowState = WindowState.Minimized;
    }
```

In my `XAML` file I didn't write anything. And it is work good. I see my notifyicon near the windows clock.
But now I need to realise with right click context menu. And I have a problem. `ContextMenu` is not a part of `TaskbarIcon`
[screenshot of the mistake in Xaml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V3PDL.png)
But if you will open link of [this exemple](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36468/WPF-NotifyIcon-2) you will see that `ContextMenu` must be include to `TaskbarIcon`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

[ContextMenuStrip](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.contextmenustrip?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) replaces ContextMenu and adds functionality.

Example use:

```
    private readonly NotifyIcon notifyIcon;
    ...
    notifyIcon = new NotifyIcon
    {
        // Icon is in Project folder with a Build Action of 'Resource'
        Icon = new Icon(Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/MyIcon.ico")).Stream),
        Visible = true,
        ContextMenuStrip = new ContextMenuStrip()
    };
    notifyIcon.ContextMenuStrip = new ContextMenuStrip();
    notifyIcon.ContextMenuStrip.Items.Add("Exit");
    notifyIcon.ContextMenuStrip.Items[0].Click += (o, e) => Close();
```

Don't forget to Dispose() of the NotifyIcon appropriately eg. in the Closed event handler of the Window.